# Same class loaded by multiple class loaders - Intellij plugin

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

Am developing a plugin to extend new project wizard for android studio using Intellij .

When I try to call AndroidSdkUtils.isAndroidSdkAvailable() am getting Assertion:null, Pasted the error below,

```
null
java.lang.AssertionError
at com.intellij.openapi.projectRoots.SdkType.findInstance(SdkType.java:207)
at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidSdkType.getInstance(AndroidSdkType.java:231)
at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidSdkUtils.getAllAndroidSdks(AndroidSdkUtils.java:462)
at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidSdkUtils.getAndroidSdkPathsFromExistingPlatforms(AndroidSdkUtils.java:443)
at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidSdkUtils.tryToChooseAndroidSdk(AndroidSdkUtils.java:853)
at com.android.tools.idea.npw.ConfigureAndroidProjectPath.putSdkDependentParams(ConfigureAndroidProjectPath.java:97)
at com.android.tools.idea.npw.ConfigureAndroidProjectPath.init(ConfigureAndroidProjectPath.java:59)
at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.dynamic.DynamicWizardPath.attachToWizard(DynamicWizardPath.java:98)
at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.dynamic.DynamicWizard.addPath(DynamicWizard.java:242)
at com.android.tools.idea.npw.NewProjectWizardDynamic.addPaths(NewProjectWizardDynamic.java:84)
at tru.NewModuleWizardDynamicExtension.init(NewModuleWizardDynamicExtension.java:27)
at NewProAction.actionPerformed(NewProAction.java:30)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:182)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter$1.run(ActionMenuItem.java:311)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(FocusManagerImpl.java:958)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(IdeFocusManagerImpl.java:124)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.actionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:281)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.fireActionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:109)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.JToggleButton$ToggleButtonModel.setPressed(JToggleButton.java:308)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
at com.apple.laf.ScreenMenuItemCheckbox.itemStateChanged(ScreenMenuItemCheckbox.java:193)
at java.awt.CheckboxMenuItem.processItemEvent(CheckboxMenuItem.java:389)
at java.awt.CheckboxMenuItem.processEvent(CheckboxMenuItem.java:357)
at java.awt.MenuComponent.dispatchEventImpl(MenuComponent.java:351)
at java.awt.MenuComponent.dispatchEvent(MenuComponent.java:339)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:761)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:866)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:654)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:381)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

This happens because findInstance method tries to compare AndroidSdkType.Class with one of the sdkType class inside a for loop, Classes are actually same but loaded by two different loaders, one from (org.jetbrains.android) and other from local loader (com.sample.sample)

How Do I solve this issue?

Because of this class loader issue, I often get classcastexception also. So when I try using different ways to develop plugin am struck with this class loader issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes as Yole said I just did this yesterday and executed plugin successfully.

This documentation gives perfect answer for my question. Think might be useful to others.

http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/plugin_structure/plugin_dependencies.html

For the sake of others, am attaching the screenshot where "android.jar" is added in the classpath of Plugin SDK.

And the following is the code snippet that I added to plugin.xml file where "org.jetbrains.android" is the plugin ID of "android.jar" plugin.

org.jetbrains.android

And also as am developing this for android studio, I was not able to run in Intellij IDE but was able to execute in android studio.

[Intellij SDK classpath screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQU8v.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the .jar files of the Android plugin to the classpath of your IntelliJ IDEA SDK, instead of adding them as a library.